# Called program fails if run through os.exec

Tags: go, openssh

I am not sure if this is a problem of the called program or if the problem is caused by the way I call the program. Because of this I start at the source code.

I need to call ssh from a program (if you are interested in the reasons I will mention them below) but ssh silently exits.

When I call `ssh -v user@remotehost` from shell this succeeds:

- the wanted debug output on stderr is shown
- I am asked for the password
- I can see the remote hosts shell

But when I do the same from within my program (`myssh -v user@remotehost` only this happens:

- I am asked for the password

Neither the debug output on stderr is shown  nor do I reach the remote hosts shell.

This is my sourcecode:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "os"
        "os/exec"
)

func main() {
        params := os.Args[1:]
        fmt.Printf("passing this to ssh: %s\n", params)
        cmd := exec.Command("ssh", params...)
        err := cmd.Run()
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
}
```

*Reason why I wrote this code: I use Ansible which calls ssh. I need to "manipulate" the parameters that Ansible passes to ssh. So far I asked on the OpenSSH  and Ansible mailing lists, there is no means in OpenSSH and Ansible to change the parameters (for others it is, but not those I need). The best suggestion I got and that I want to implement is to provide an alternative ssh command to Ansible, use that to receive and modify the parameters and pass them on to the real ssh.*

Answer (score 1):

Are you capturing `Stdout` and `Stderr` from `cmd`? This is where the respective outputs of the command is sent to. The documentation for [exec.Command](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command) has a really good example on this.

In your case, you'll also want to setup `Stdin` so that you can pass the password for example.

Here's a really basic example based on your code:

```golang
package main

import (
  "bytes"
  "fmt"
  "log"
  "os"
  "os/exec"
)

func main() {
  params := os.Args[1:]
  fmt.Println("Passing this to ssh: %s", params)

  var stdin  bytes.Buffer
  var stdout bytes.Buffer
  var stderr bytes.Bufer

  cmd := exec.Command("ssh", params...)
  cmd.Stdin  = &stdin
  cmd.Stdout = &stdout
  cmd.Stderr = &stderr

  if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  fmt.Println("Stdout: %s", stdout.String())
  fmt.Println("stderr: %s", stderr.String())
}
```

Since `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are all `bytes.Buffer`s, you can read and write from them just like any other buffer.

You might also want to consider using the `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh` package which provides a native SSH interface for Go instead of using sub-processes.

Comment: You can see the complete code in my question. Stdout is shown in the screen otherwise I would not see the the password prompt. It is handled automatically, so I assume stdin and stdout should be too. I do not want to create a new ssh, especially because I do not even know what Ansible needs. How would I connect the received stderr and stdout to the caller of my program ?

Comment: @Marged if you want to propagate the error up you can write to `os.Stdout` and `os.Stderr` by using `fmt.Fprint`. Something like `fmt.Fprint(os.Stderr, stderr.String())`. This will require you to capture `cmd.Stdout` and `cmd.Stderr` as I did in my sample code.

Comment: Thank you. Does this cause problems with long running tasks. If I understand you correctly this would gather all output and send it when the called program exits. Can it be done "live" ? And how would I use this in stdin ?

Comment: @Marged In that case, I believe `exec.Command.StdoutPipe()` and the similar functions are what you're interested in as they allow you to dynamically read and write data to the command until the command exits. Additionally, `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh` also provides `StdoutPipe()` and such as member functions of the `ssh.Session` struct.